# geckodriver: how to specify "moz:firefoxOptions" on node.config for selenium grid

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-grid2

I am running tests on selenium grid using nunit C# with:

- selenium-standalone-server: v3.3.1
- selenium webdriver: v3.3
- geckodriver: 0.15
- firefox: v52

Firefox is not installed on the default location and so I get following exception on running tests:

> Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I want to specify Firefox executable path on the capabilities section of `node.config` file of selenium grid. How do I do that with new geckodriver?

`firefox_binary` is now obsolete and it uses `"moz:firefoxOptions"`, but I don't know how to specify it in selenium node's config file.

This is what I am doing in the config file, but its not working:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "moz:firefoxOptions": {
        "binary": "D:\\Browsers\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
        },
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ]
.........
```

Comment: Support is best in Firefox 55 and greater, although generally the more recent the Firefox version, the better the experience as they have more bug fixes and features. Some features will only be available in the most recent Firefox versions, and we strongly advise using the latest Firefox Nightly with geckodriver. Since Windows XP support in Firefox was dropped with Firefox 53, we do not support this platform. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding firefox executable folder path to `PATH` system environment variable. Once you add the path to `PATH` environment variable its not necessary to add it to node.config